# MSSQL - refresh / duplicate set of tables from another database as a single transaction

Tags: sql-server

Ignoring any reasons why I shouldn't be doing this ...

But what would be the easiest way to refresh a set tables from another MSSQL database as a single transaction?

Context:

- 10 tables
- DDL won't change
- Refresh is 100%!
- ~100Megs (relatively small)

I would want to do this as a script (TSQL or SQL), and avoid any advanced Server changes (replications, etc).

Will a simple SELECT * INSERT INTO , wrapped in a transaction be the best thing to do??

Comment: Do these tables have any indexes or constraints on them that need to be maintained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sole question is to migrate those tables from a different database within the same server then there are multiple ways

You can run a `insert into select from` statement like

```
insert into db1.db1table
select * from db2.table;
```

You can create a DB dump (using SSMS) which will script the table schema along with all the data and that `*.sql` file you can run against your another database. probably you can use `SQLCMD` or `SSMS` if you prefer.

Third option is to, do a `full DB backup` and `restore` the same.

Comment: full DB restore is treated as a separate transaction?  - or will there be a period of downtime?

Comment: Yes it's counted as separate transaction. There will be downtime since you can't restore if there are user connected to that database. Restoring needs the DB to be changed in single user mode.